# Use struct in while loop

Tags: loops, struct

I am using a while loop in which a struct named sol is updated every iteration, I need the sol of the i-2 iteration to obtain the new solution at i. How can I do this?

while (i<40)

sol(i) = function of sol(i-2)

end

what I do now is saving the struct sol to a file and then load the file in the new iteration, it seems to work but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: is not very clear, try to put your code. 

However, from what I understand, maybe the while loop is not very suitable. 
in any case, you can do so: int i = 0; 
while () {
i ++; 
} 
and use the index as you feel better

Comment: Welcome on SO. Could you please give us a little more detail/code example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a structure(map for example) to store the values obtained in "i-2" iteration.

In a structure like a map you could store for the key(i) the value(i-2).

```
map<int, int> yourMap;
yourMap[i+2] = i;
```

I hope tis solves your problem. Best regards Luis